# Shortening a long if else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a long `if else` statement:

```
 rnd = rand(1..1000)
 if rnd >= 600
   0
 elsif rnd < 600 && rnd >= 350
   1
 elsif rnd < 350 && rnd >= 270
   2
 elsif rnd < 270 && rnd >= 200
   3
 elsif rnd < 200 && rnd >= 150
   4
 elsif rnd < 150 && rnd >= 100
   5
 elsif rnd < 100 && rnd >= 80
   6
 elsif rnd < 80 && rnd >= 50
   7
 elsif rnd < 50 && rnd >= 30
   8
 else
   9
 end
```

I would like to shorten it. Is it possible?
My rubocop swears at this long method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
RANGES = {
  (0...30) => 9,
  (30...50) => 8,
  (50...80) => 7,
  # ...
  (350...600) => 1,
  (600...1000) => 0
}

rnd = rand(1..1000)
RANGES.find { |k, _| k.cover?(rnd) }.last
```

Answer (score 5):

Great answers already!  Just chiming in since I had a suspicion that ruby could handle this with a `case` statement, and it appears to be able to do so:

```rb
rnd = rand(1..1000)

case rnd
when 600.. then 0
when 350...600 then 1
when 270...350 then 2
...
else 9
end
```

Regardless of the approach taken, you're going to have to specify the ranges somewhere, so I think using something like a case statement is appropriate here (sorry! It doesn't shorten the code more than a few lines).  Using a hash would also be a great approach (and might allow you to move the hash elsewhere), as other commenters have already shown.

It's worth mentioning, with ruby ranges, `..` means that the range is *inclusive* and includes the last value (1..10 includes the number 10), and `...` means the range is *exclusive* where it does not include the last value.

The top case `600..` is an [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges), which means it will match anything greater than 600. (That functionality was added in ruby 2.6)

Comment: Not that you are wrong in any way regarding inclusive/exclusive ranges; however in a case statement that is organized the way you have this matter is inconsequential since 600 would hit the first line just as 350 would hit the second regardless of `..` or `...`

Comment: Oh great call out @engineersmnky!  I like the explicitness with the `...` personally, but love that it'd work both ways :).

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your conditions by using only the lower bound.
And you can avoid repeting `elsif` because it is cumbersome

```
rnd = rand(1..1000)
lower_bounds = {
  600 => 0,
  350 => 1,
  270 => 2,
  200 => 3,
  150 => 4,
  100 => 5,
  80 => 6,
  50 => 7,
  30 => 8,
  0 => 9,
}

lower_bounds.find { |k, _| k <= rnd }.last
```

Comment: We can even clean up the hash generation via `[600,350,270,200,150,100,80,50,30,0].each_with_index.to_h`

Comment: I like your approach. Answers that use a `case` statement with ranges need to check both ends of each range, even though only the upper end needs to be checked. This approach does not have that weakness.

Answer (score 2):

```
MX = 1000
LIMITS = [600, 350, 270, 200, 150, 100, 80, 50, 30, 0]
```

---

The required index can be computed as follows.

```
def doit
  rnd = rand(1..MX)
  LIMITS.index { |n| n <= rnd }
end

doit
  #=> 5
```

In this example `rnd #=> 117`.

---

If this must be repeated many times, and speed is paramount, you could do the following.

```
LOOK_UP = (1..MX).each_with_object({}) do |m,h|
  h[m] = LIMITS.index { |n| n <= m }
end
  #=> {1=>9, 2=>9,..., 29=>9,
  #    30=>8, 31=>8,..., 49=>8,
  #    ...
  #    600=>0, 601=>0,..., 1000=>0}
```

Then simply

```
def doit
  LOOK_UP[rand(1..MX)]
end

doit
  #=> 3
```

In this example `rand(1..MX) #=> 262`.

---

If speed were paramount but `MX` were so large that the previous approach would require excessive memory, you could use a binary search.

```
def doit
   rnd = rand(1..MX)
   LIMITS.bsearch_index { |n| n <= rnd }
end

doit
  #=> 5
```

In this example `rnd #=> 174`.

See [Array#bsearch_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index). `bsearch_index` returns the correct index in O(log n), n being `LIMITS.size)`. `bsearch_index` requires the array on which it operates to be ordered.